# python linprog, lp appears to be unbounded

Tags: python, scipy, linear-programming

I'm trying to write a simple LP in Python to solve rock paper scissors, here is my code before:

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog

obj = [0, 0, 0, -1]

A = [[0, 1, -1, -1], [-1, 0, 1, -1], [1, -1, 0, -1], [1, 1, 1, 0]]
b = [0, 0, 0, 1]
pb = (0.0, 1)
wb = (None, None)

res = linprog(obj, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, bounds=(pb,pb,pb,wb),options={"disp": True})
print(res)
```

Unfortunately when I run this, I get the following message:

```
    'Optimization failed. The problem appears to be unbounded.'
```

But considering my LP is as follows:

```
f = -w

pp - ps - w = 0
-pr + -ps - w = 0
pr - pp - w = 0
pr + pp + ps = 1
0 < pr, pp, ps < 1
```

I don't see why this is unbounded. If I'm either messing up the construction of my LP or there is a syntax error could someone let me know.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `A_eq` instead of `A_ub`?

Comment: You also probably accidently wrote a minus in `-pr + -ps - w = 0`?

Comment: Yeah, I needed to use A_eq, and I had one or two equality errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write in your call:

```
res = linprog(obj, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, bounds=(pb,pb,pb,wb),options={"disp": True})
```

So this means that you write an `A_ub * x <= b_ub` instead of `A_eq * x = b_eq`. As a result your program looks like:

```
minimize f = -w
wrt.
    pp - ps - w <= 0
    -pr + -ps - w <= 0
    pr - pp - w <= 0
    pr + pp + ps = 1
    0 < pr, pp, ps < 1
```

Since we here have in the last lines `... - w <= 0` and we aim to minimize `-w`, this means that the optimal is `w` being positive infinity.

Your program suggests however that you want equality bounds. So we can write this with `A_eq` and `b_eq` parameters:

```
res = linprog(obj, A_eq=A, b_eq=b, bounds=(pb,pb,pb,wb),options={"disp": True})
```

This then gives us:

```
>>> res = linprog(obj, A_eq=A, b_eq=b, bounds=(pb,pb,pb,wb),options={"disp": True})
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: -0.000000   
         Iterations: 4
>>> print(res)
     fun: -0.0
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 4
   slack: array([0.66666667, 0.66666667, 0.66666667])
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.        ])
```

This thus means that we have:

```
pr = 1/3
pp = 1/3
ps = 1/3
w = 0
```